# Strange Behavior With NSTextField and an NSAttributedString Placeholder

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, appkit

I'm adding a placeholder to an NSTextField:

```
NSTextField *textField = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 30.0)];
NSAttributedString *string = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello, World"];
[textField.cell setPlaceholderAttributedString:string];
```

This works, but when I focus the text field, the placeholder disappears, even when the `stringValue` is empty.

If I set the placeholder with just the `setPlaceholderString:` method, the placeholder remains until the `stringValue` is not empty.

Is this just bad behavior on AppKit's part or am I missing something?

The above is a simple example.  I'm using the attributed string so I can set font and color attributes.

Comment: This seems to just be a bug. Yea!

Comment: were you able to find a solution or a work around?

Comment: No, you either have to put up with the placeholder's default color or hand write your own.

Comment: Thats sad. Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you have specified a binding for the control? If yes, your placeholder attributed string would be overwritten by the binding's null placeholder.

It should be possible then to bind the control programmatically and specify the attributed string as the option for the null placeholder like this:

```
[textField bind:@"value" toObject:self withKeyPath:@"textFieldValue" options: @{NSNullPlaceholderBindingOption:string}];
```

One more thing. I found out that it will work from the 10.9 SDK.